# Close connection when testing is done

Tags: c#, unit-testing, httplistener

I want to use unit testing to test the functionality of my HTTP Listener. But I have a hard time making it stop listening when it's finished.

```
    private HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();

    public ListenerTests()
    {
        listener.Start("1234");
    }

    //Test if the listener can respond
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestResponse()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        string response = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:1234/");
        Assert.IsNotNull(response);
    }

    //Test if the server can stop without issues
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestStop()
    {
        listener.Stop();
    }
```

If I only run the TestStop() test then it will always stop listening and while running second time it works fine. If I run both it will work fine first time, but the second time the "test execution engine" is still running whereas the port is not available.

I think running Stop() after all tests would solve the problem... But I can't figure out how?

I tried using Ordered Tests but that had all sorts of different issues. Even though I changed the port on it to listen it would seemingly randomly use one I picked previously, which would then be unavailable forever. Also, it's far from ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the TestCleanupAttribute to clean up everything after your tests are done.

```
[TestCleanup]
public void TestStop()
{
    listener.Stop();
}
```

And put your Init in the ClassInitializeAttribute:

```
[ClassInitialize]
public void ListenerInit()
{
    listener.Start("1234");
}
```

[MSDN: Unit Testing Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243147(v=vs.80))

Comment: ClassInitialize needs to be static. My class however isn't static. I instead used TestIntialize. It appears to work the same. Thanks for the comment, though. I'm actually really new to unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

From the information available under [Structure of Unit Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182517%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [Anatomy of a Unit Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182517%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you should create a cleanup method with the attribute `ClassCleanUp` to stop your HttpListener after all the tests have been completed.

In addition to the `ClassCleanUp` tag, you can tag your method that is creating your HttpListener with `ClassInitialize` to ensure that the HttpListener is always called before the tests are executed, removing the requirement to call the constructor that you have currently.